# Sql Server Database Projects - missing template in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, database-project

In VS2012 I used Sql Server Datbase Projects to manage my databases.  I have tried to add a Db Project to a new VS2013 solution but I can't seem to find the template.  I've looked online and in the installed templates.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to install SSDT tooling for VS 2013 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn864412

Answer (score 6):

To me, it is listed under "Other Languages". I have VS 2013 professional

[image: VS menu Installed/Templates/Other Languages/SQL Server]

Answer (score 3):

VS2013 lists "SQL Server" after the "Visual F#" option in the "New Project" window. Clicking on this "SQL Server" option shows one template called "SQL Server Database Project".

Perhaps that option was not installed for your initial VS2013 installation.

Comment: No, I don't have a SQLServer folder (I've gone through all subfolders!)

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: Unfortunately that link only installed BIDs and some other things, not the template that was required, kind thanks for you answer though