# Can't create SQL Server database project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, new-project

Please I need help, I want to create a SQL Server database project in Visual 
Studio 2013.

I tried File -> New -> Project .. but I can't find the SQL Server option in the menu:

[image]

I found out that I had to install the SSDT for VS2013 from this link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42313

After downloading the SSDT I only got the Business Intelligence Option as shown in the menu in the picture.

Some suggested to download Visual Studio update 3. I tried to download the updates from this webpage of Microsoft https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2829760/overview-of-visual-studio-2013-updates

but none of the download links work!

What else can I do to create SQL Server project in VS2013?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server Database Projects - missing template in VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605007/sql-server-database-projects-missing-template-in-vs-2013)

Comment: @R.Richards Answers to that question didn't help me unfortunately.

Comment: I see. The link in the accepted answer on the other question pointed to a non-Business Intelligence version of SSDT, which made me think that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I tried to download Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 from the tools menu in the Visual Studio and it finally works, I can create SQL Server database project in VS now.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help.